# the elements of a character vector are lists - how to combine them

Tags: r

given that I have a vector:    x <- c("m1", "m2", "m3")   and every element m1, m2 and m3 is a list e.g.

```
m1 = list(a=1:3, b=2:4, c=1:10)  
m2 = list(a=0:3, b=0:4, c=6:10)  
m3 = list(a=1:30, b=1:2, c=6:10)
```

I want to be able to create "super list" using loop:

```
mylist <- list()  
for(i in x)mylist[[i]] <- ...??....
```

when `i="m1"` then `mylist[["m1"]] <- m1`

any suggestion would be appreciate.

Robert

Comment: Not sure why would need a loop if you already have three named list, e.g. `mylist <- list(m1=m1, m2=m2, m3=m3)` will do the job. (BTW, as it is defined, `x` is already a list.)

Comment: Perhaps you could give a broader context of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is, given a vector of object names, combine the given objects into a list.

```
mylist <- lapply(x, get)
names(mylist) <- x
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly I've been searching for this useful function: get. It works of you write: lapply(x, get)

Comment: Small improvement: `sapply(x, get, simplify = FALSE)` .  This creates the list of lists and sets their names all in one step.